# NextJS 14 API route memory limit

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js14

I'm trying to increase memory limit for my api route using app directory with nextjs 14 and Vercel.
Vercel should be able to allow increase to a 3GB memory limit on pro plan.

Route path is `src/app/api/process/hook/route.ts`

What I was hoping to work is setting `vercel.json`.

```
{
  "functions": {
    "app/api/process/**/*": {
      "memory": 3008
    }
  }
}

"app/api/**/*.ts" doesn't work also
```

But for some reason, memory is still set to 1GB.
Does anyone know how to set it properly?